# Proof that $\sqrt{4}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ of course wrong but where is the flaw?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fake-proofs

Assume $$\eqalign{
\sqrt{4}\in\mathbb{Q}&\Longrightarrow(\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z})\sqrt{4}=\frac{a}{b}\text{ and }\gcd(a,b)=1\\
&\Longrightarrow 4b^2=a^2\Longrightarrow a\text{ is even}\\
&\Longrightarrow a=2k\Longrightarrow b^2=4k^2\Longrightarrow b\text{ is even}\\
&\Longrightarrow \gcd(a,b)\ne1 \text{ contradiction}}$$
Where's the flaw?

Comment: The simplest way is to plug in the numbers which you know witness the failure, and see for yourself what goes wrong. In this case, $a=2, b=1$. Then you see that $a=2k$ does not mean that $1=4k^2$. If anything, $1=k^2$.

Comment: How in the world did you get from $a=2k$ to $b^2=4k^2\text{ ??}$  If $a=2k$ then $a^2=4k^2$, but that doesn't mean $b^2=4k^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What Asaf said. ;) By the way, this is an awful way to write a mathematical reasoning, and mostly unacceptable except these short tests where you really have no time to write properly. It's not only formally incorrect, it's also hard to read (exponentially harder as the length of the proof increases). If you had written this properly, you likely wouldn't have even made the mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get $4b^2=a^2=(2k)^2=4k^2$, so $b^2=k^2$.

Comment: i.e. the third line should be "$\Longrightarrow a=2k\Longrightarrow 4b^2=4k^2$", which does not lead to a contrdiction

Comment: That was so obvious thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You simplify by 4 without throwing the 4 on the RHS away.